# PHP image uploader rename image?

Tags: php, image, rename, uploader

I'm trying to rename an image when uploading it to my server. Is there generally an easy way of doing this? Below is the php code I'm using. I want to rename it as a variable I'm passing through as a hidden field from a html form.

```
 //variable from hidden field on form which is from mysql database
 $imageName = $_POST['image_rename'];

 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 8000000))
   {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

     if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
       {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
       }
     else
       {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       }
     }
   }
 else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";
   }
```

Comment: don't use unchecked input from the client, it could be potentially dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `move_uploaded_file()` function; add the name you want within the function. Just make sure to grab the proper extension, something like:

```
$parts=explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
$newName=$imageName.'.'.$parts[(count($parts)-1)];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'../uploads/'.$newName);
```

Comment: you can use 
end($parts); instead of count - 1

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/" . $imageName);
```

Comment: Nope, because he said he would provide the file name through the hidden input. `$imageName = $_POST['image_rename'];` ;)