# PHP Compress Image and rename

Tags: php, gd, image-compression

I found [that](https://jsfiddle.net/h6wnvaoe/) code [here](https://makitweb.com/how-to-compress-image-size-while-uploading-with-php/)

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

  // Getting file name
  $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];

  // Valid extension
  $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');

  // Location
  $location = "images/".$filename;

  // file extension
  $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

  // Check extension
  if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){

    // Compress Image
    compressImage($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$location,60);

  }else{
    echo "Invalid file type.";
  }
}

// Compress image
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

  $info = getimagesize($source);

  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

  imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

}

?>
```

That work great but I cant figure it out how to rename the image file when is saved.
I know how to rename it with [move_uploaded_file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368319/php-image-uploader-rename-image) but [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476578/how-to-move-compressed-image-file-php) with compress_image function.

I tried adding/changing variables but didn't work I get to save the image with the original name on it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your destination path should be the new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, if someone arrives here with the same question its for you:

index.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>How to Compress Image and Rename while Uploading with PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

            // Getting file name
            $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];

            // Valid extension
            $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');

            // Location
            $location = "images/".$filename;

            $imageName = "myNewImageName"; // New image name. 

            // file extension
            $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

            $path = "../withdrawals_receipt_uploads/".$imageName.'.'.$file_extension;

            // Check extension
            if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){  

                // Compress Image
                compressImage($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $path, 60);

            }else{
                echo "Invalid file type.";
            }
        }

        // Compress image
        function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

            $info = getimagesize($source);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

            imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        }

        ?>

        <!-- Upload form -->
        <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='imagefile' >
            <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='upload'>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @Joseph_J

Comment: I was about to ask this question, stack suggested this in the list. Thanks @Irvıng Ngr you just saved a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function you do not need to check for the MIME type.

In fact `imagecreatefromstring()` will return false if it cannot create a resource, meaning the string was not a valid image.

So you can use that as an additional and more reliable test to make sure you have a valid image.

I have went through your code and changed some things and commented along the way.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

  //Getting file name
  $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];

  //Valid extension
  $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');

  //Location
  $path = 'images/'; //<--Just the path to the directory.
  $imageName = 'myNewImageName.jpg'; //<---Rename your image. 

  //File extension
  $file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  //Check extension
  if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_ext)){

    //Compress Image    
    compressImage($filename, $path, $imageName, 60);

  }else{
    echo "Invalid file type.";
  }
}

//Compress image
function compressImage($file, $path, $imageName, $quality) {

  //Check to see if the directory exist. If not create it with write permissions.
  if(!file_exists($path)){

    mkdir($path, 0777);

  }

  //Check to see if the directory is writable. If not change permissions.
  if(!is_writable($path)){

  chmod($path, 0777);  

  }

  $resource = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file)); //Creates an image resource and it does not matter what MIME type.
  imagejpeg($resource, $path . $imageName, $quality); //Will save image to new path and filename.
  imagedestroy($resource); //<--Don't forget to free your resources.

  //Change your permissions back to what they need to be.
  chmod($path, 0755);
  chmod($destination, 0644);

}
```

Comment: Hi Joseph thanks for ur answer, i run ur code and i get these errors:

`Warning: file_get_contents(myimage.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mydirectory/upload/index.php on line 32`

`Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in /mydirectory/upload/index.php on line 32`

`Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /mydirectory/upload/index.php on line 33`

`Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /mydirectory/upload/index.php on line 34`

Comment: you should be using `file_get_contents($file)`..  Where `$file` is you uploaded file or a path to a valid file.

Comment: I know it's an old post but, can someone tell me where did the $location variable came from? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Samuel Ramzan There is no variable named `$location` in my code sample.  If you are referring to Irvıng Ngr code sample then the `$location` variable is a reference to the `$filename` variable appended to the path where the image in question is located.